# help reading the confusion matrix of the randomForest function in R, which are the predicted values on the confusion matrix of randomForest function?

Tags: r, random-forest, confusion-matrix

Can someone tell me which are the actual values and which are the predicted values on the confusion matrix of randomForest function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows are the actual labels, the columns are the predicted:

```
library(randomForest)
rf = randomForest(Species~.,data=iris)
rf$confusion

           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          4        46        0.08
```

We can check the predicted distribution and you see it tallies with the column sums of the above:

```
table(predict(rf))

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        50         51         49
```

And we can get the confusion matrix again:

```
table(iris$Species,predict(rf))

             setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         47         3
  virginica       0          4        46
```